# DDD: Calculator(Service) with lots of input

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I was wondering how to tackle this one. I have a model in which a lot of calculations are done. Now I was wondering what to do about the following problem:

I can split up all the calculations in specific CalculatorServices, but in the end I would have like one CalculatorService which is kind of the root of the calculation. This will require a lot of input.

So I can go 2 routes from this:

- Provide Entities to the calculator(services), seems logical to me.
- Make the calculators(services) totaly agnostic of the Entities, so they can be used without providing an Entity graph. I think this is strange because it would make me kind of duplicate the Entity graph in some sort of input objects graph, henche (almost) duplicate code.

I could of course try to put the calculations on the different Entities and go from there.

Which route would you guys/girls take or are there any others?

UPDATE:

The calculations are not to be used for reporting. The calculations are in fact (part of ) the domain, since the domain here is a mathematical model of forces, but I cannot go in to the specifics without breaking a non disclosure agreement :(

So to draw an example; we could best think of the calculators (= services/entities?) like the ones in an analytical trading system.

Comment: If you can provide more info about your specific domain...

Comment: What kind of calculations? Calculations are usually reporting concerns which are addressed on the Query side of things, hence without going through the domain object model at all...

Comment: See my update, domain is for a big part the calculation in itself.

Comment: Why would you not pass in the Entity that contains all necessary data? Is it possible to pass in an aggregate root and have the services use whatever they need?

Answer (score 0):

> Which route would you guys/girls take or are there any others?

One way is to separate calculation process into parts:

1. Importing data
2. Calculation
3. Results presentation

Importing data loads bulk of data (inputs) through service into database.

Calculation applies business rules to data in the database, creates and saves results into database.

Results presentation provides methods to view calculation results from various angles.

Main idea is to localize as much data in the service as possible so it doesn't go from client to service on every calculation method call.